# How do I troubleshoot udev rule not applying at boot time?

Tags: ubuntu, udev

Until recently my udev rules for my realtec Wifi USB were being applied on boot but no longer.

This coincidentally occurred after an update from kernel 5.14 to 5.16.

The rule still exists in the 40-usb_modeswitch.rules file

```
# Realtek 8211CU Wifi AC USB
ATTR{idVendor}=="0bda", ATTR{idProduct}=="1a2b", RUN+="usb_modeswitch -K -v 0bda -p 1a2b"
```

The rule still works if I manually trigger it after booting :

```
$ sudo udevadm trigger
```

The WIFI adapter is recognized and begins to work as expected.

However the rule is not applied on at boot.

I can see in the system logs that there are no usb_modeswitch messages after the 17-Apr (1 week ago).

Not sure what to troubleshoot here.

System is Ubuntu 21.10.

Any ideas appreciated.